# UIActivityViewController init method in Swift doesn't play nice

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've this bit of code

```
var dataToShare = "My score is \(currentScore). Come and play with me!"
var act: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: dataToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
```

But there's this bugging error that keeps me crazy- "Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'activityItems:applicationActivities:', expected 'nibName:bundle:')"
Now this code seems to work everywhere else except in my code. I've tried deleting DerivedData, to no avail. What can be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `activityItems` needs to be passed as an array:

```
var act = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [dataToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: Sir, you just made my day. Didn't think it was that obvious :/